# grab text from html and use it and concatenation to access object property

Tags: javascript, html, object, concatenation

I don't know if this is possible, and I'm pretty new to JavaScript and programing, but here is what I'm trying to do:

I have a table in HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
      <td id="w1t1">kc</td>
      <td id="w1s1">30</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I have an object in JS:
`const kc = {name: kc, color: "red", score: 0};`

I would like to grab the text like so:
`let team1 = document.getElementById("w1t1").textContent;`

this should set the value of team1 to "kc".
I would then like to concatenate with ".score" to access kc.score like so:

```
function test(){
    let t1 = team1 + ".score";
    console.log(t1);
}
```

I would like the value of t1 to be 0, which is the value of kc.score, but instead it's value is "kc.score".

is there anyway to get this to work?

Comment: Where `const kc` goes from? Is it declared in your code above or it goes from api somehow?

Comment: If your object was a member of an another object, say `const objects = {}; objects.kc = {..., score: 0};`, then you could access it as `objects[team1].score`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far I understand you want the score by team1 so here is how you can do this

```
// First store name of the team in a variable like you are doing
const team1 = document.getElementById("w1t1").textContent;
// now in team1 var we have value of kc

// modify your object a bit
const  team = { kc: {name: kc, color: "red", score: 0} };

console.log(team[team1].score)
```

Let me know if this works!

Comment: OMG thank you so much, it worked like a charm. you are Awesome!!!

Comment: You are awesome too keep it up man.